# How can i subtract time in one sub document document (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created one collection using array concept.

```
use test
db.time.insert({ "employeeid" : 1, "timing" : [{var : "temp", timein: new Date(), timeout: new Date()}]})
```

After created the document, I have update the timeout after 5 mins.

```
db.time.update({"employeeid" : 1, "timing.var" : "temp"},{$set : {"timing.$.timeout" : new Date()}})
```

I have two queries.

1) can i store only time(hh:mm:ss) in timein, timeout fileds?

2) how can i subtract sub document timein timeout values?

Comment: what do you mean by subtract values ? Please modify, show us your data, query and expected output

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar I mean subtract the time. for example timein : 11:01:52, timeout : 12:05:58 . now subtract timeout-timein the total hours 01:04:06. I need like this type of answer 01:04:06(hh:mm:ss). and which command used for store only time without date?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my takes:

> 1) can i store only time(hh:mm:ss) in timein, timeout fileds?

No you can't. Date type field will always be a full date. However, while reading you can chose to read only hh mm and ss part of it
like:

```
d.getHours()
d.getMinutes()
```

but it sounds like too complex.
Best thing I can suggest is to use milliseconds. User store and read particular time in timeInMillies instead of a Date type. 
Having a NumberLong field in mongo, it will be easier to compare, add, subtract and while reading you can convert it back to Date.

---

> 2) how can i subtract sub document timein timeout values?

I am taking a difference in seconds, if you want millisecs remove the divide my 1000

```
db.time.aggregate([
    {
       $unwind:"$timing"
    },
    {
       $project:{
          diff:{
             $divide:[
                {
                   $subtract:[
                      "$timing.timeout",
                      "$timing.timein"
                   ]
                },
                1000
             ]
          }
       }
    }
])
```